# Set attribute for dynamically added each elements

Tags: angularjs

How can i set 'type attribute' for each added dynamic buttons? 
In below code, label names were changing perfectly,, and also i could able to set 'type attribute' to first added button, but remaining button types are not changing properly.. can u pls check it out and solve this to me pls ..

[Working DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/3fGazzk3s3Cwps6dBCgP?p=preview)

**Updated:**

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngSanitize']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $compile) {
  var counter = 0;
        $scope.buttonFields = [];

  $scope.add_Button = function(index) {
  $scope.buttonFields[counter] = {button: 'Submit'};
        var buttonhtml = '<div ng-click="selectButton(buttonFields[\'' + counter + '\'])"><button id="button_Type">{{buttonFields[' + counter + '].button}}</button>//click//</div>';
        var button = $compile(buttonhtml)($scope);
        angular.element(document.getElementById('add')).append(button);
        $scope.changeTosubmit = function () {
            var el = document.getElementById("button_Type");
            el.setAttribute("type", "submit");
            compile(el);
        };
        $scope.changeToreset = function () {
            var el = document.getElementById("button_Type");
            el.setAttribute("type", "reset");
            compile(el);
        };
        $scope.changeTocancel = function () {
            var el = document.getElementById("button_Type");
            el.setAttribute("type", "cancel");
            compile(el);
        };
        ++counter;
    };

    $scope.selectButton = function (val) {
        $scope.buttonField = val;
$scope.showButton_Types = true;
    };
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">

  <head>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.0-rc.0/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <button ng-click="add_Button($index)">Add Buttons</button>
<hr>
 <div id="add"></div>
 <form ng-show="showButton_Types">
      <div>
        <label>Button Name(?)</label><br/>    
        <input ng-model="buttonField.button">
      </div>
      <div>            
        <label>change button types(?)</label><br/>
        <input ng-click="changeTosubmit()" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Submit
        <input ng-click="changeToreset()" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Reset
        <input ng-click="changeTocancel()" name="submit" type="radio">&nbsp;Cancel
      </div>
 </form>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie Hi.. i updated my code..

Comment: sorry @TrueBlueAussie .. i did remove .. :)

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting "all the buttons" via `document.getElementById("button_Type")`. That's the problem: `getElementById` returns the first item it can find with the given id.

Try to use document.querySelectorAll() instead (which will always return an array).

Comment: But i want to add different types of attr to every button ,, i want to set first button 'type to Submit', second button 'type to Reset'.. if i use **document.querySelectorAll()** showing an error as _Not enough arguments to Document.querySelectorAll_ .. how to solve this, can u try this for me pls?

Comment: The core problem you're facing is "how do I select the proper elements"? I can only advise to you to catch up with the basics of CSS selectors. I recommend reading this article for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started

Besides that: in your example you should NOT add the same id to every button as the id attribute should be unique. Try using classes and of course, when using document.querySelectorAll() you need to pass the proper selector as an argument.